# Trouble making a button unique

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a situation in which I use this java script for a single button and it works like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','a.btn-success',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var myProductID=$(this).data('productid');
        var myUserid=$(this).data('iam');
        var postData={productID:myProductID,userid:myUserid};

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type:"POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                
                $('a.btn-success').remove();
                $('a.btn-success').remove();
                $('#ajax-response').html('<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Added</button></p>');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And my link:

```
                    <!-- Add to cart button -->
                    <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-block" data-productid="<?php echo $current_product->product_id; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $userID; ?>" href="../incl/ajax-add-to-cart.php">Add</a></p>
                    <p id="ajax-response"></p>
```

And this works!!

What I now want is to use it with a list of products in which each product has besides its picture a button  "add"  which is represented by:

```
 a.btn-success
```

What I am doing is something like this:

```
              <!-- Add to cart button -->
                    <?php echo "<p><a class='btn btn-success'$button_id' btn-xs btn-block' data-productid=' $current_product->product_id;' data-userid='$userID' href='../incl/ajax-add-to-cart.php'>Add</a></p>"?>
                    <p id="ajax-response"></p>
```

Notice that I am trying to append a variable  "$button_id" to the name of the button (it is really an an a tag with the style of a bootstrap button).

Then in the JavaScript I do as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','a.btn-success'.$button_id,function(e){ //added button id
        e.preventDefault();
        var myBookID=$(this).data('bookid');
        var myUserid=$(this).data('iam');
        var postData={bookID:myBookID,userid:myUserid};

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type:"POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                
                $('a.btn-success'.$button_id).remove();//added button id
                $('a.btn-success'.$button_id).remove();//added button id
                $('#ajax-response').html('<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Tillägt</button></p>');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But it does not work. Can anybody help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change your function into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var button_id = '<?php echo $button_id; ?>';
    $(document).on('click','a.btn-success'+button_id,function(e){ //added button id
        e.preventDefault();
        var myBookID=$(this).data('bookid');
        var myUserid=$(this).data('iam');
        var postData={bookID:myBookID,userid:myUserid};

        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type:"POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                
                $('a.btn-success'+button_id).remove();//added button id
                $('a.btn-success'+button_id).remove();//added button id
                $('#ajax-response').html('<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Tillägt</button></p>');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I assume this JavaScript file is inside PHP file where you can put `$button_id` value into JavaScript variable using simple `<?php echo $button_id; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

try this:
check your button using firebug tool,i think it is not unique.

```
<?php echo "<p><a class='btn btn-success".$button_id." btn-xs btn-block' data-productid='".$current_product->product_id."' data-userid='".$userID."' href='../incl/ajax-add-to-cart.php'>Add</a></p>"?>
```

and also change `$button_id` to `<?php echo $button_id;?>` in your js.

Comment: Thank you the problem I have is that by appending the unique id I loose the bootstraps style. Is there any way to preserve it?

Comment: exa: `<a class='newbtn".$button_id."...`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how does this preserve the boostrap style for the button?

Comment: then the when echoing the button the data-productid is not set to the product's id....

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to make your btn unique to make this work 
( especially when it's not by your logic).

I would go for it with the following changes:

use $(e.target) instead of $(this)
For ajax response - 
 In the html you may transform it from

```
<p id="ajax_response" ></p>
```

to

```
<p class="ajax_response" id="ajax_response_<?php echo $prod_id; ?>" ></p>
```

Or you may rearrange the html a bit to make them part of the same logical parent and 
 then use jquery functions like .closest() //searches up parents and .find() finds in children

```
$(document).on('click','a.btn-success',function(e){    
e.preventDefault();
var $btn = $(e.target); // you may console.log( $btn ); here if you wish so

var myProductID= $btn.data('productid'); // all references to $(this) are replaced by $btn
var myUserid=$btn.data('iam');
var postData={productID:myProductID,userid:myUserid};

$.ajax({
    url: $(btn).href,
    type:"POST",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                
        var $ajaxResponseDiv = $('#ajax_response_'+myProductID);
        $btn.remove();
        $ajaxResponseDiv.html('<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block">Added</button></p>');
    }
});
});
```

Best regards